# pip freeze gives different version from pip --version

Tags: python, pip

I am on Windows 10 and just installed Python 3.7.4. I installed virtualenv using **pip install virtualenv**, and i got the message that i installed 16.7.2 while 19.2.1 is available. I then used **python -m pip install --upgrade pip** to upgrade.

Here is the issue: when i type **pip freeze** on Powershell, i am getting this:

virtualenv==16.7.2

but when i type **pip --version**, i am getting this:

pip 19.2.1 from c:\users\user1\python\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

Can you please let me know why pip freeze still shows the old version?

Thanks.

Comment: Virtualenv is 16.7.2, while pip itself is 19.2.1? Can you provide the output from the command?

Comment: `pip freeze` shows the list of installed packages. You have `virtualenv` of latest version installed. If you want to update `pip`, issue `pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip` and `virtualenv` are 2 different cases where `pip` is mainly used for installing python packages and `virtualenv` for utilizing virtual environments while development.

The following command updates only `pip` not virtual env

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

If you think you still need to upgrade virtualenv (of course if a new version is available). Please follow the following syntax without specifying a version.

```
pip install [package] --upgrade
```